# Let $\Delta_n$ be the smallest distance between any two of these points. Show that $n^{\theta}\Delta_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability.

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, uniform-distribution

This is a qual problem。

Let $n$ points be iid uniformly distributed on the unit circle. Let $\Delta_n$ be the smallest distance between any two of these points. Show that $n^{\theta}\Delta_n\rightarrow 0$ in probability as $n\rightarrow \infty$ for all $0<\theta<2$.

I started by denoting $\Delta_n$ and it got related to the angle, which got really messy and didn't think that's the right way. So I 'm wondering whether I can find some hints or solutions here. Thanks.

Comment: ok so your question is really about the order of magnitude of $\Delta_n$ as $n \to \infty$

Comment: @user1952009 Just edited it.

Comment: for $\theta < 1$ it is obvious, since $\Delta_n \le \frac{2 \pi}{n}$.

Comment: Here's an idea, although it might need more justification. Fix a point, and consider the event that no other point lies within $2\pi n^{-2}$ of it. This probability is obviously upper bounded by $(1-n^{-2})^{n-1}$. Now condition on this, and look at a second point. The probability that no other lies within $2\pi n^{-2}$ of this is similarly upper bounded by $(1-n^{-2})^{n-2}$. Continuing, you'll get that the probability that $\Delta_n = \Omega(n^{-2})$ is less than $(1- n^{-2})^{(n^2 - n)/2}$, which decays as $\exp(-O(n^2))$.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Actually, $(1-n^{-2})^{(n^2-n)/2}\to e^{1/2}$, not zero. But the argument works pretty well to show what the question actually asks, starting with the event that no other point lies within $2\pi/n^\theta$ of some given point, for some $\theta<2$.

Comment: @Did Ach, yes, thanks. What a silly error :-/

Comment: Typo: $e^{-1/2}$, not $e^{1/2}$.